# I want to delete Media Page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress is a good website develop tool.
So there are so many pages such as Post, Comment, Media.
But I need only Post & Comment Page.
How can I do this?
I want to know the way without using Theme.

Comment: check the referance - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page for more info

Answer (score 1):

Plz add this part of code to your `functions.php` file

```
function remove_menus() {
    remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );                  //Dashboard
    remove_menu_page( 'jetpack' );                    //Jetpack* 
    //remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );                   //Posts
    remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );                 //Media
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );    //Pages
    remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );                 //Appearance
    remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );                //Plugins
    //remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );                  //Users
    remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                  //Tools
    //remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );        //Settings
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus', 999 );
```